# Storing $_SESSION variable in class

Tags: php, session

I want to be able to store a $_SESSION variable from my class but it does not seem to be working. I searched stackoverflow and googled for quite some time and was not able to find sufficient information to know whether this is possible or not.

Can I store a $_SESSION variable in my class? I cant seem to access it outside of the class.

```
class myClass {

    public function authorizeLogin($email,$password) {

        global $_SESSION;

        //Query to authorize user
        $q_auth = $this->query("
            SELECT first_name,last_name,email,date_registered,access_id
            FROM users
            WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'");

        $authorized = $q_auth ? 1 : 0 ;

        if($q_auth) {
            //Loop through values and assign in session
            foreach($q_auth as $key => $value) {
                $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $authorized;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you calling session_start before you authorizeLogin

Comment: I am running session_start before I include and declare my class in this order:

session_start();
include 'myClass.class.php';
$myClass = new myClass();

Comment: How do you know that `"it does not seem to be working"`? I see no debug output in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION` is superglobal - no need to use `global`.

Your code looks fine - but did you run `session_start();`?

Comment: I run it in my config.php before I declare my class.

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken, but I believe you have to include the class before you start the session.  Then create your object.  For some odd reason that I cannot explain I remember hearing this somewhere.

So the order should be include("myClass.class.php");  session_start();  $myClass = new myClass();